# How to redirect to a component page from redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react and redux in my web-app . So my scenario where i am stuck is , on click of a button i am calling the redux action js where i am calling an API , and in then block i have written the conditions that if these passes then i need to redirect to a diff page but i dont have to change the URL of the page just the different component i need to render . I am using below code for that , but it seems control never goes into my component from action.

Action Js

```
export function fetchData(data) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    let request = apiRequest(data);
    
    return fetchAPICall(request).then(resp => {
      
      if( resp.data.id==1){
         <OtherComp  data={data} />
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
  }
}
```

fetch Api call js

```
export function fetchAPICall(body) {
  return fetch(SomeURL {
    headers: headerSchema,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

OtherComp is just a sample static Component and the control doesn't goes to this component at all. Can someone please suggest where i am going wrong?

Comment: you want to change the route in a condition which is if `resp.data.id==1`, am i right?

Comment: @yahyaparvar yes , but i do not want url to be changed, so i guess the browser history push will not work.

Comment: Assign a bool variable and with the condition make it true/false then at the component where you want to show the component in condition, check if the bool is true or not

Comment: i do not get exactly what you are suggesting , i am already calling the component inside the if condition . But the problem is it is not actually getting called .

Comment: i see what you trying to do, you should not return a component directly in the action instead you should assign a variable in the reducer and change the component conditionally in a parent component also it is about the `{data}` as well, can i see your reducer and the component where you are calling the action? also can i know a concept of what you want to achieve? is the `OtherComp` a loading indicator or a component that shows the action parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

npm install --save history

In my project I initialise browser history in index.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
```

Redirect in the action:

```
export function fetchData(data) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    let request = apiRequest(data);
    
    return fetchAPICall(request).then(resp => {
      
      if( resp.data.id==1){
          browserHistory.push('/pathToRedirect')
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: i do not want to change the URL , i want to render another component but without the URL Change.

Comment: @shubham then save your data in redux and this check isApiDataReceived (true/false)
and in component where you dispatch the fetchData action and want to show in view sense this check isApiDataReceived  if data is recieved then render this OtherComp  if not then blank